# placeholder of textfield is not working extjs 6.0.2

Tags: textfield, placeholder, extjs6-classic

i'm using textfield in a window, And there with that textfield placeholder is not working .
Will you please tell me what's the reason.

here is my code.

```
   Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'edit box',
        closable: false,

        draggable:true,
        height: '80%',
        width: 1000,
        scrollable :true,
        liveDrag:true,
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'form',
            scrollable:true,
            defaults: {
                msgTarget: 'side'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                cls: 'instruction-text-static',
                overCls: 'over-instruction-text-static',
                layout: {
                    type: 'table',
                    columns: 2
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'label',
                    html:'label',{
                    xtype:'container',
                    items:[{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        ui:'link-btn',
                        text: 'cancel',
                        style:{
                            float:'right'
                        },
                        handler: function (cmp) {
                           this.up('window').hide();
                        }
                    },{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        ui: 'green-btn',
                        text: 'save',
                        style:{
                            float:'right'
                        },
                        handler: function (cmp) {
                          //my logic    
                        }
                    }]
                },{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                   placeholder: "add title",
                    value:record.data.title,
                    width: 430,
                    itemId: "instructionTitleEdit",
                    name: 'instructionTitle1',
                    colspan: 2,
                    style:{
                        'margin-left':'10px'
                    },

                },{
                    xtype: 'label',
                    html:'a label'
                },{
                    xtype:'htmleditor',
                    value:record.data.description,

                },{
                    xtype: 'label',
                    html:'one lable'
                },{
                    xtype: 'label',
                    html:'my label'
                },{
                    xtype:'htmleditor',
                    scrollable:true,
                    value:record.data.examples,
                    height: 400,
                    width: 475,
                    name: 'instructionExample',

                },{
                    xtype:'htmleditor',
                    scrollable:true,
                    height: 400,
                    width: 475,
                    name: 'instructionRad',
                    value:record.data.hint,

                }]
            }]
        }]


    }).show();
```

But that pakceholder thing is not working
Please help me out
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `placeholder` property for textfields. You should use [emptyText](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#cfg-emptyText) instead.

Comment: i'm not sure but this only works if the component is rendered.